# How to dynamically decide what to cache

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, memcached

### THE PROBLEM

I want to add caching to my web application.

Since caching everything will kill my server and caching nothing will do the same thing, I am wondering how can I **decide what is worth caching on the fly**.

Is there any way to do that?

In other words, I need an algorithm that would constantly:

- **cache data order by their popularity**...
- ...but only to a point where **server is running out of resources**

### MY SOLUTION

My attempt to solve this problem assumes that we cache **all data** and proceed as follows:

1. If there is no cached version create one, but **only for a short time** (e.g. 1 second)
2. If there is cached version, use it and **extend it's life for another second**
3. If there is cached version AND **current minutes amount is divisible by 5**, go to point 1
4. Run cron which **constantly monitors server resources** and if they are short, **frees** some of them.

Comment: you question is constructive, but i suggest a simpler solution, why dont you manually decide which to cache, first obvious thing is to cache connection to the database

Comment: That's the point. I prefer automating the whole process, rather than picking files to cache manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to teach a program - not an easy - to know what is important to be cached now and what is not.

This should be decided by the architect or engineer. Because only he knows what should be cached. If you do not know what has to be cached, you should better study the domain of your application and observe her behavior.

Anyway, to teach a program, what it should cache, you should know what cache before.

The application must know the popularity of data, as you said. So, the application knows what cache.

Comment: You're right, but the popularity of different content changes over time. Of course, admin can monitor these changes and update cache rules manually, but my solution seems to be doing it automatically, doesn't it?

Comment: You must cache by popularity order, eg. if the file's popularity is >= 5 should be cached, if is < 5 should not be cached. Put this script in a cron. Simple. Your solution is complex and can put your cache in a loop(items 1 and 3 of your solution).